# Trust between 2 Certificate Authorities

Tags: windows, ssl, openssl, request, ca

I have created 2 certificate authorities

`req -new -x509 -keyout privACAkey.pem -out ACAcert.pem -days 1024 -config openssl.cfg`

`req -new -x509 -keyout privBCAkey.pem -out BCAcert.pem -days 1024 -config openssl.cfg`

and I want the CA of the organisation B to send a request for a certificate of the same self-signed certificate in CA A. How to do this cross-sign certification ?

Comment: [Google: openssl "cross certify" ca](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+"cross+certify"+ca).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [PKI - CA Cross-Certify Certificate with OpenSSL?](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.encryption.openssl.user/14524):

> First, use 'openssl x509 -x509toreq' to create a CSR from the
>   certificate you want to cross-certify, then use 'openssl ca' to sign
>   it, and use a specific extension section in the configuration file
>   (use the -extensions option).  Alternatively, the CA you want to
>   cross-certify with could send you the CSR they used to create their CA
>   certificate, and you could send them yours.
>
> Cross-certification is really not that magic.  You do need to keep
>   track of policies, how you map policies, path lengths and things like
>   that, which is why I suggest you have a specific configuration section
>   for this purpose.  Of course, you might just not care, and in that
>   case, the extension v3_ca should be good enough.

Comment: Could you please give me a code example to do that ? Thank you for spending your time !

Comment: It will take a small project to create a CSR and perform the CA signing. I'm looking at 4 source files in one of my projects. What have you tried?